# coding (unicode) hex to octal

Tags: python, sql, unicode

I read a text file, which has some characters like that `'\260'` (it means `'°'`), and then I add it to DB (sqlite3).

After that, I try to get the information from DB, but the sql-query will be built with `'\xb0'`(it means `'°'` too), because I get this information from XML file.

I try to replace hex characters with octal chracters: text = `text.replace(r'\xb0', '\260')` but it doesn't work, why? I cannot build correct sql-query.

Maybe there are some solutions for this problem e.g. encode, decode etc.

Answer (score 3):

`\260` *is the same thing* as `\xb0`:

```
>>> '\xb0'
'\xb0'
>>> '\260'
'\xb0'
```

You probably want to *decode* your input to unicode and insert that instead. If your data is encoded to Latin 1 then decode:

```
>>> print '\xb0'.decode('latin1')
°
```

`sqlite3` can handle unicode just fine, and by decoding you make sure you are handling text values, not byte values, which can differ from codec to codec.

Comment: ye, but select * from xxx where a='\xb0C' is not the same as select * from xxx where a='\260' and this is my problem. Should i write select * from xxx where a='\xb0'.decode('latin1')?

Comment: @user2973395: Use sql parameters; `cursor.execute('select * from xxx where a=?', (u'\xb0',))`.

Comment: @user2973395: don't make the query unicode, only the parameters.

Comment: one more point, I must the result write to other text file, and in the text file is valid only this form '\260', it means I must convert '\xb0' to '\260'.

Comment: @user2973395: You'll have to do that manually when writing. Perhaps use a regular expression when replacing specific bytes by their octal representations.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: but it doesn't work. e.g.  text = text.replace(r'\xb0', '\260')

Comment: Use raw string literals or escape the backslash by doubling it. `r'\260'` or `'\\260'`.

Comment: I have tried with r'\260' and '\\260', but as I said, it doesn't work. Strange.

Comment: Create a new question with that problem then, perhaps.

Comment: but this issue is my question ;)

Comment: You have *two* issues; database querying and writing escaped values to a file.